# Error with EF when trying to save changes

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an angular 8 app with .net core web api 2.1 and MS SQL SERVER.
I have login and logout implementation for users.

After the user logins, he can add or delete programming langugages.

When I perform a delete operation, I get the error

> database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually effected
>   5 rows

But the code works properly for finding that particular user and the ID of the programming language that he wants to delete.

Here is the image from the table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqvSE.jpg
As you can see there are no duplicates.

I think it is something about Concurrency Conflicts.  That's why I added a try-catch block with DbUpdateConcurrencyException.

It works sometimes and sometimes not.

Here, you can find the definiton for the table https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnPiE.jpg

When I try the following method to delete Users from MS SQL, it works as it should:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteProgrammingLanguage(string userId, int plId)
        {

            UserPL ps = new UserPL();
            try
            {
                ps = await _context.PlUsers.Where(x => x.UserId == userId && x.ProgrammingLanguageId == plId).SingleAsync();
                _context.PlUsers.Remove(ps);

               await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }


            return Ok(ps);

        }
```

Comment: What is the definition of the table? Do you have a primary key defined, and what is it?

Comment: Hello Sir.https://imgur.com/a/YMCYkNy here is the definition of the table

Comment: i can delete on same way users from this table from sql it makes no problem for MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this solution.

public IActionResult DeleteProgrammingLanguage(string userId, int plId)
        {

```
        using (_context)
        {
            // Fetch a person from database and change phone number
            var ps = _context.PlUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId && x.ProgrammingLanguageId == plId);
            // Change the person's name in the database to simulate a concurrency conflict
            _context.PlUsers.Remove(ps);

            var saved = false;
            while (!saved)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Attempt to save changes to the database
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    saved = true;
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                {
                    foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
                    {
                        if (entry.Entity is UserPL)
                        {
                            var proposedValues = entry.CurrentValues;
                            var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

                            foreach (var property in proposedValues.Properties)
                            {
                                var proposedValue = proposedValues[property];
                                var databaseValue = databaseValues[property];

                                // TODO: decide which value should be written to database
                                // proposedValues[property] = <value to be saved>;
                            }

                            // Refresh original values to bypass next concurrency check
                            entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new NotSupportedException(
                                "Don't know how to handle concurrency conflicts for "
                                + entry.Metadata.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return NoContent();

        }
```